# How to get form validated using PHP, and getting all error messages to display at once?

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement

I had a form that I used PHP to validate, using a bunch of nested if statements. It worked but the problem was of course the error messages would display one at a time. I want to get them to display all at once. So I tried to rewrite my code without using nested conditional statements. I have spent atleast 4 hours attempting and nothing is working. Could someone give me some advice? It would be much appreciated...Also, I am unsure if it is possible to write an if statement and if the condition is met, have it execute no code. That is what my code is attempting to do at the moment, and I am sure this is a horrible practice, but I can't think of another way of doing it.

```
    <?php

    if($_POST['submit']==1)
    {
        //$submit = strip_tags(isset($_POST['submit']));
        $fname =  strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
        $usernamereg = strip_tags($_POST['usernamereg']);
        $passwordreg = strip_tags($_POST['passwordreg']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $emailcheck = strip_tags($_POST['emailcheck']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die ("There is a problem connecting to the database");
        mysql_select_db("user_db",$connect) or die("Couldn't find the database."); 

        $queryusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usernamereg'");
        $numrowsusername = mysql_num_rows($queryusername);  
        $queryemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $numrowsemail = mysql_num_rows($queryemail);

        if($fname&&$lname&&$usernamereg&&$passwordreg&&$email&&$emailcheck)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $all_fields = 'All fields must be filled in';
        }
        if (strlen($usernamereg)>25||strlen($fname)>25||strlen($lname)>25)
        {
                $length_error = "First name, last name, and username cannot be longer than 25 characters";

        }
        if($numrowsusername = 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $username_error ='username already taken';
        }
        if(strlen($passwordreg)<6)
        {
            $password_error ="Password must be atleast 6 characters";

        }
        else
        {
            //some form of password encryption
        }
        if($email != $emailcheck)
        {
            $emails_no_match = "Emails don't match";
        }
        if($numrowsemail = 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $email_in_use_error ="This email is already in use";
        }


if(isset($all_fields)||isset($length_error)||isset($username_error)||isset($password_error)||isset($emails_no_match)||isset($email_in_use_error)==1)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                $queryget =mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(date,fname,lname,username,password,email,emailcheck)VALUES('$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck')");
                echo "You have been registered!";
            }

        }   
        ?>


Here is my form code

    <form action ='' method = 'POST' name ='regform'>
                <table width = '500px'>
                <tr>
                    <td id ="form_title" align ='left'>Sign Up Here</td>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="form_subtitle" align ='left'> 100% Free</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align ='left'><input type ='text' name = 'fname' placeholder = 'First Name' class = 'firstname' /><input type ='text' name='lname' placeholder = 'Last Name' class = 'lastname' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align ='left'><input type ='text' name = 'usernamereg' placeholder = 'Username' class = 'username2' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php 
                        if(!empty($username_error)){
                            echo $username_error;
                        }
                    ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align ='left'><input type ='password' name='passwordreg' placeholder = 'Password' class = 'password2' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php
                            if(isset($password_error)){
                            echo $password_error;
                        }
                        ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align ='left'><input type ='email' name = 'email' placeholder = 'Email' class = 'email'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php 
                        if(!empty($emails_no_match)){
                            echo $emails_no_match;
                        }
                    ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align ='left'><input type ='email' name = 'emailcheck' placeholder = 'Re-enter Email' class = 'emailcheck'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php 
                        if(!empty($email_in_use_error)){
                            echo $email_in_use_error;
                        }
                    ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php 
                        if(!empty($all_fields)){
                            echo $all_fields;
                        }
                    ?> </td>
                </tr>

                <td align='center'><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' id= 'regbutton' value = 'Register' /></td>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you give us more details please (original form) and a better description of the problem.  It's difficult to understand it.

Nevertheless, in your posted code are some faults i guess...

```
if($numrowsusername = 0)
```

is an assignment.  so, in this case, always false...  should be

```
if ( $numrowsusername == 0 )
```

same for ' if($numrowsemail = 0) '

And BTW, yes it is possible to have nothing executed if if-statement is true.  Don't put anything between brackets, or better, just put a ; in between for readability.

Comment: I added my form code. Thank you for your response. Not to ask stupid questions, but if i put a semi colon in between the brackets, when my code executes, and the condition is met, will the code just jump to the next part of the code (in my case another if statement) or does it stop executing?

Comment: You can simply check this, but yes, it will go to the next if statement.

Comment: and @user3407857? Is all this code in the same php source?

Comment: If you're building if-statements which have empty bodies, you're better off inverting the logic so that it checks for the opposite condition, eg `if ($numrowsusername == 0)` becomes `if ($numrowsusername > 0)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you TwoWholeWorms I will try inverting them now. And @PBR yes it is

Comment: @TwoWholeWorms.  The opposite of 'if ($numrow == 0)' is NOT 'if ($numrow > 0)'!!! it is 'if ($numrow != 0)'.  It's kind of a big difference...

Comment: Agreed, however if your queries are returning negative-quantity arrays, you have a different and much more serious problem. o.o

Answer (score 0):

You can put your errors into an array and then display its contents if any errors occur.

```
<?php

$errors = array();
if ($_POST['submit'] == 1) {
    //$submit = strip_tags(isset($_POST['submit']));
    $fname =  strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
    $usernamereg = strip_tags($_POST['usernamereg']);
    $passwordreg = strip_tags($_POST['passwordreg']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $emailcheck = strip_tags($_POST['emailcheck']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die ("There is a problem connecting to the database");
    mysql_select_db("user_db",$connect) or die("Couldn't find the database."); 

    $queryusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usernamereg'");
    $numrowsusername = mysql_num_rows($queryusername);  
    $queryemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $numrowsemail = mysql_num_rows($queryemail);

    if (!$fname || !$lname || !$usernamereg || !$passwordreg || !$email || !$emailcheck) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields must be filled in';
    }

    if (strlen($usernamereg) > 25 || strlen($fname) > 25 || strlen($lname) > 25) {
        $errors[] = "First name, last name, and username cannot be longer than 25 characters";

    }

    if ($numrowsusername > 0) {
        $errors[] ='Username already taken';
    }

    if (strlen($passwordreg) < 6) {
        $errors[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters";
    } else {
        $passwordreg = md5($passwordreg);
    }

    if ($email != $emailcheck) {
        $errors[] = "Emails don't match";
    }

    if ($numrowsemail > 0) {
        $errors[] ="This email is already in use";
    }

    // If no errors occurred, insert the user into the database
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $queryget =mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(date,fname,lname,username,password,email,emailcheck)VALUES('$date','$fname','$lname','$usernamereg','$passwordreg','$email','$emailcheck')");
        echo "You have been registered!";
    }

}
```

Now, where you want to display your errors, just put this code:

```
<?php if (count($errors)) { ?><ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li></ul><?php } ?>
```

I would suggest you do so underneath the "100% free" line.

Also, I recommend you take a look at the [PHP PSR-2 coding standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) document. That document, along with its predecessors [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) define good practice for writing readable PHP code which is easily debuggable.

As an additional point to note, `strip_tags()` is not sufficient to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks. You need to sanitise your `$_POST` variables before they are used in an SQL query. For integers and floats, I recommend the following syntax:

```
$myInt   = (isset($_POST['myInt'])   ?   (int)$_POST['myInt']   : null);
$myFloat = (isset($_POST['myFloat']) ? (float)$_POST['myFloat'] : null);
```

For strings, you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to ensure that the variable is properly processed as follows:

```
$myStr = (isset($_POST['myStr']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myStr']) : null);
```

So, your `$fname` variable line becomes the following:

```
$fname = (isset($_POST['fname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']) : null);
```

And so on and so forth for the rest of your input variables.

Ideally, you want to be using PDO and prepared statements, but that's outside of the scope of this question. Also, the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in a future version, probably quite soon. It's recommended that you use the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) library instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will rewrite the code with mysqli functions.

Comment: Don't forget to change the lines using strip_tags as well! Also, you'll probably want to check that usernames only contain valid characters, and that e-mail addresses are valid too. There are plenty of questions on SO which can tell you how to do this. :)

Comment: At the moment, my form inputs are not being added to the form even when all of my validation checks are met. Does it have to do with my first if statement when I check to see if the submit button has been clicked..

Comment: You need to add this to each `input` field before the `/>`: `<?php echo (isset($fname) ? ' value="' . htmlentities($fname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '"' : ''); ?>` Obviously, you need to change `fname` to the appropriate `name=""` attribute for each element.